# .net Webview2 control different behaviour WebBrowserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview, activex

i implemented a usercontrol containing the new webview2 control and made it "comvisible". when I use the usercontrol in a winform application, and navigate to an url, the right page is shown. But when i try to insert the registered control in the activeX Test container, i do not get any paged displayed. After that I added a button and some other standard controls to the user control. this controls are shown. If i replace the webView2Ctrl with the WebBrowserControl, everthing works. So what is the difference between the controls?

Thx,
coontry_boy

Comment: The main difference is 10 years of development. WW2 accepts JavaScript invokations as main and the only way to interact with web page. If you want some additional button in HTML, you may insert it with JS. If you want to add Winforms control above the WW2 control, just add it to the container's `.Controls`.

Comment: Hello,
first many thx for your fast response. based on https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/comcom/article.php/c16257/Create-an-ActiveX-using-a-Csharp-Usercontrol.htm . i inserted only WW2 Control instead of buttonctrl and textctrol. after building the example i get no content shown on the ww2 control. buf if i replace the ww2 control with the windowbrowser-control it works well.

Comment: ActiveX is obsolete technology and not supprted in Microsoft Edge https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_other-msedge_win10/enable-activex-control-in-microsoft-edge-latest/979e619d-f9f2-47da-9e7d-ffd755234655, you may achieve it with other technologies. What exactly do you want to achieve? UI in browser? Make it with HTML and Javascript.

Comment: One more thing https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/67 - _I've confirmed with the team that IE mode in WebView2 is not in plan to be supported._ Thus let the ActiveX rest in peace.

Comment: i want to achive running ww2 control as activex under vb6 (classic)

Comment: WebView2 doesn't support ActiveX and there's no plans to support it.

Comment: i know it. therefore i want to embed it in a c# (winform) usercontrol with exposing com properties see in above link of codeguru example. running that usercontrol in a winformapplication it works fine. but not as activex wrapper.
And when i exchange the ww2 with old webbrowser-ctrl in the same activex project, it works. so there must be a difference at activex runtime environment.

Comment: Probably yes. But I still can't catch the idea how must it work (e.g. for user). Where do you want to embed the control. Another app?

Comment: currently we are porting a large vb6 application to .net. but we can do that not at one go. So we need a solution for our vb6 included webbrowser control which is showing html prepared machinedata. this control should be replaced by the new chromium based wv2control. to do that without any impact, i thought it would be possible to do that by an activex wrapper. First dry was to do that by a c#-usercontrol with a nested wv2-ctrl and make set comvisible to true and implement register-method and all that stuff to reach a bindable com object.

Comment: The answer is easy, use legacy `WebBrowser` if you need `ActiveX`. Change it to WW2 when you'll finish the migration and ActiveX requirement become not actual anymore.

Comment: this could take about 2 years, and we need it now, to do not went out of support

Comment: Not an easy thing then. I'm sorry. As alternative, try Chromium Embedded Framework - `CefSharp`. Afaik there was some ActiveX compartibility.